# Stop fixed block on last element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following snippet (open snippet as full page) :

```css
#container_1{
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 150px;
}

.block1{
    background: green;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#moving_block{
    z-index: 0;
    background-color: purple;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#footer{
  background-color: gray;
  height: 5000px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="container_1" class="container">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="row block1">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <p>TEXT</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row block1">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <p>TEXT</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row block1">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <p>TEXT</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row block1">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <p>TEXT</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row block1">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <p>TEXT</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div id="moving_block" class="col-md-3 affix">
            <div class="row">
                <p>TEXT</p>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>

<section id="footer">
MY FOOTER
</section>
```

I would like to stop the purple block when he encounter the last green block.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using `position:sticky`.

I consider bootstrap V4 for this since there is builtin function for sticky. I also simplified the code to keep only the relevant one for the demo:

```css
#container_1 {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 150px;
}

.block1 {
  background: green;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.block1:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#moving_block {
  background-color: purple;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

#footer {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 5000px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="container_1" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-5 col-offset-1">
      <div class="row block1">
          <p>TEXT</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row block1">
          <p>TEXT</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row block1">
          <p>TEXT</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row block1">
          <p>TEXT</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row block1">
          <p>TEXT</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <div id="moving_block" class="overflow-auto position-sticky sticky-top">
          <p>TEXT</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<section id="footer">
  MY FOOTER
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,but how to make the purple move down without touching the top (on scroll) ?

Comment: @executable instead of using  `sticky-top` add manually the value you want like `top:40px` for example

Comment: Hey, can you explain the purpose of this part ? `.block1:not(:last-child) {  margin-bottom: 15px; }`

Comment: @executable to have margin for all element expect the last one so that the sticky will stop exactly where the last element is